# CastClassException in custom fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, classcastexception

So i have this code with the error that appears in the logcat. It shows an error with the cast im using for my custom fragment for some reason.

I've searched before asking and i tried everything:

Importing the v4.support.fragment

Check the Manifest to see if its not declared there

Extend Fragmentactivity in my main class

I still have it, any ideas pls?

Fragment Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TapFragment extends Fragment {

private Button[] _Btns_SinUso;
private Button[] _Btns_AUsar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buttons, container,
            false);
    setLayout(RootView);
    return RootView;
}

public void setLayout(View v) {
    int Dif = GameManager.readPreferences(getActivity(),
            GameManager.KEY_DIF);
    switch (Dif) {
    case GameManager.GAMEDIF_MED:
        _Btns_AUsar = new Button[GameManager.SIZE_5X5.length];
        _Btns_SinUso = new Button[GameManager.T5X5_UNUSED.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _Btns_AUsar.length; i++)
            _Btns_AUsar[i] = (Button) v
                    .findViewById(GameManager.SIZE_5X5[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < _Btns_SinUso.length; i++) {
            _Btns_SinUso[i] = (Button) v
                    .findViewById(GameManager.T5X5_UNUSED[i]);
            _Btns_SinUso[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Main Activity Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Game extends FragmentActivity {

    private Activity _Actividad;
    private boolean _StartGame;
    private Button _Btn_Indicator;
    private int _GM, _Dif, _Multi, _GT, _TimeReady, _Sc, _PPH, _ValorCorrecto,
            _Combo;
    TapFragment _FragButtons;
    private TextView _TxtVw_Score, _TxtVw_Timer;
    private Timer _C = new Timer();
    private String _IniciarTxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
       _FragButtons = (TapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Fr_ButtonContainer);
    // _FragButtons.setColors();
    // setGame();
    declare();

    // Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
    // new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE},
    // new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
    // _BtnTap=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_Tap1);
    // _BtnTap.getPaint().setShader(textShader);

}

public void declare() {
    // DECLARACION
    _Sc = 0;
    _TimeReady = 4;
    _StartGame = false;
    _Actividad = Game.this;
    _Dif = GameManager.readPreferences(_Actividad, GameManager.KEY_DIF);
    _PPH = GameManager.readPreferences(_Actividad, GameManager.KEY_PPH);
    _Multi = GameManager.readPreferences(_Actividad, GameManager.KEY_MULTI);
    _GM = GameManager.readPreferences(_Actividad, GameManager.KEY_MODE);
    _TxtVw_Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtVw_Score);
    _TxtVw_Timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtVw_Timer);
    _Btn_Indicator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_Indicator);
    _IniciarTxt = getResources().getString(R.string.WordGo);
    switch (_GM) {
    case GameManager.GAMETYPE_1MIN:
        _GT = 61;
        break;
    case GameManager.GAMETYPE_100T:
        _GT = -1;
        break;
    }
}
```

XML of the main file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ReLa_Main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.albertoha94.games.Tap.Game"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TxtVw_Timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TxtVw_Score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TxtVw_Timer"
    android:text="@string/WordScore"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/Fr_ButtonContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adGame"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TxtVw_Score"
    class="com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
        12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.albertoha94.games.Tap/com.albertoha94.games.Tap.Game}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1754)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1000)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at com.albertoha94.games.Tap.Game.onCreate(Game.java:48)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1699)
    12-11 00:04:23.865: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    ... 11 more

According to the logcat, my error happens in the onCreate() Method, when im casting my fragment.
```

EDIT----------------------

I tried the solution of using the solution that Kristy said and a new error appeared, something about being unable to inflate:

```
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.albertoha94.games.Tap/com.albertoha94.games.Tap.Game}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1754)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1000)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:539)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:601)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:654)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:439)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:351)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:307)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1693)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at com.albertoha94.games.Tap.Game.onCreate(Game.java:48)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1699)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    ... 11 more
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: TapFragment(Context,AttributeSet)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:674)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:503)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:511)
12-11 22:33:04.108: E/AndroidRuntime(16353):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: what on line 48 in Game.Java? Can you update that line in question?

Comment: The cast of my fragment.

  _FragButtons = (TapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Fr_ButtonContainer);

Comment: try android:name="com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment" instead of class="com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment"

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Im a moron. Turns out both of your methods were correct.
I originally had the TapFragment and Game class together(TapFragment was inside Game), when i decided to separate the classes with differente .java files, i cut the code from TapFragment and paste it in a new file but I completely forgot to erase the class that was inside the Game class, leaving an empty class.

```
public TapFragment extends Fragment{}
```

Since this line of code was still there, I think the program selects this one instead of the one I wanted to, so I erase this line and the code worked. Thanks n_n

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   <com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment
       android:id="@+id/Fr_ButtonContainer"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/adGame"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/TxtVw_Score"
     />
```

Instead of:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/Fr_ButtonContainer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/adGame"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/TxtVw_Score"
class="com.albertoha94.games.Tap.TapFragment" />
```

Comment: I tried and now the error changes o.o
An error about inflating the Layout, ill edit it in the post so you can see it.